# Нужно проверить наличие класса у всех элементов списка, и если этот класс есть у всех элементов, добавлять кнопке активный класс

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<button>test<button>

<ul>
 <li class='list list-active'>
     lorem 1
</li>
 <li class='list list-active'>
lorem 2
</li>
 <li class='list list-active'>
lorem 3
</li>
 <li class='list list-active'>
  lorem 4
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (document.querySelectorAll('.list').length === document.querySelectorAll('.list-active').length) {
  document.querySelector('button').classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.active {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>

<ul>
 <li class='list list-active'>
    lorem 1
  </li>
  <li class='list list-active'>
    lorem 2
  </li>
  <li class='list list-active'>
    lorem 3
  </li>
  <li class='list list-active'>
    lorem 4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогли)

Comment: @ВладимирЛиподат если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа)